# Count how many posts came out after the last post ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following question in ActiveRecord.

Model and Example Fields

```
Post [ title:string content:string color:string ]
```

Imagine that my model receives recurring posts, but sometimes a specific post comes with a "white" color.

Now imagine that a post with the color "white" came out about 30 minutes ago, and several posts came out with other colors in those 30 minutes.

The problem is that I can't imagine how to count how many posts came out after the last post with white color!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While both of the proposed solutions will work they require instantiating a `Post` object which is unnecessary in my opinion instead we can make this a single query like so

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord 

  scope :posts_since, ->(color) {
         where(arel_table[:created_at].gt(
                  select(arel_table[:created_at].maximum).where(color: color).arel))}
end
```

Callable as

```
Post.posts_since(:white)
```

Resulting Query

```
SELECT 
  posts.* 
FROM 
  posts 
WHERE
  created_at > (SELECT MAX(posts.created_at) FROM posts WHERE posts.color = 'white'))
```

To "count" you can just add `count` e.g. `Post.posts_since(:white).count`

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for your reply! This use of scope seems very interesting, excuse me but I'm crawling with active record... But I tested your code and it returned me

comparison of String with Arel::Table failed

Comment: @ViniciusR.Vieira I apologize I wrote this by hand without testing. I have updated accordingly to make this work as described.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```rb
def self.count_post_by_color(color)
  where(created_at: Post.where(color: color).last.created_at..Time.current).count
end
```

Comment: Hello friend, how are you? your method worked too! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.count_posts_last_white(last_post_id, last_white_id)
   self.where(id: last_white_id..last_result_id - 1).count
end
```

I asked the question a short time ago, but battling my mind I ended up finding a solution

Comment: You can change this to `self.where(id: last_white_id...).count` an endless exlusive range will result in `>` e.g. `"WHERE id > last_white_id"`